# How can I specify a refresh rate in glances?

Tags: ubuntu, monitoring, refresh-rate, glances

How can I specify a refresh rate in [glances](https://github.com/nicolargo/glances)?

By default, glances refreshes itself every 3 seconds. I tried using `glances -t 1` as well as `glances --time 1` to lower it to 1 second, but it seems to be ignored. Is there anything else I should do ?

I use glances v2.11.1 with psutil v5.4.3 and Ubuntu 16.04 LTS x64.

Answer (score 2):

From version `3.1.3`:

You can use `glances -w -t 1`